# openlayers 4.4.1 does not show my geojson correctly

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, geojson

I have received some shapefiles which i transformed into a geojson file using mygeodata.cloud (also used mapshaper.org, but no difference) for my application. After struggling for some time, i got the shapes on the map, but they kept showing in the Gulf of Guinea.

I recalculated the coordinates manually, but still the positions are off, shapes are in sea but all shapes should be on land.

How it should show and what my result looks like:
http://www.webwards.nl/osm/geojson_results.jpg

This is my complete geojson file:
http://www.webwards.nl/osm/geo.json

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GeoJSON</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var styles = {
        'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            lineDash: [4],
            width: 3
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
          })
        })
      };

      var styleFunction = function(feature) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
      };

      var geojsonObject = {} // see geojson file

// this is where i recalculate the coordinates. I know this is not the way to do it :-)
$.each(geojsonObject.features, function(k, feature) {
    $.each(feature.geometry.coordinates[0], function(l, coordinate) {
        geojsonObject.features[k].geometry.coordinates[0][l][0] = coordinate[0] + 440150;
        geojsonObject.features[k].geometry.coordinates[0][l][1] = coordinate[1] + 6454650;
    });
});

      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
      });

      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: ({
            collapsible: false
          })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.8224924, 53.1263859]),
          zoom: 10
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? I'm pretty experienced with javascript, but i'm a total newbie to openstreetmaps/openlayers.

Thanks in advance!

best regards, Sander

Answer (score 0):

after some more research, i've found the solution in proj4js.

I've included the library;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

defined EPSG:28992;

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992", "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs");
```

and changed the projection of the view;

```
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([5.8224924, 53.1263859], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:28992'),
        zoom: 10,
        projection: 'EPSG:28992'
    })
```

now it works like a charm!